# moment.js second argument not working

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Not sure why the following is returning `false`. The format specified in the second argument is exactly what I've specified while initializing a Bootstrap Datetimepicker.

```
moment('Fri 5 Jan, 2018 - 05:00 PM', 'ddd d MMM, YYYY - hh:mm A').isValid()
```

I am trying to convert datetime in the first argument to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm` format, but `moment` keeps returning an Invalid Date error.

Comment: its not a correct date format

Comment: this returns true for me (valid)

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: @Riscie it gives false

Comment: @UmeshAawte Chrome 63.0

Comment: change the date format of datepicker and try

Comment: Make sure you are using correct/latest moment version as support to some field values started in latter versions. Eg. Support for A is started in version 2.13.0 of Moment.js

Comment: In any error case even because of version it will return false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) you should use a capital **D** for the day digit (5 Jan), whereas you now have a lowercase **d**.

```
moment('Fri 5 Jan, 2018 - 05:00 PM', 'ddd D MMM, YYYY - hh:mm A').isValid();
```

[Live example](https://codepen.io/nielsdB97/pen/MrEqeJ)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **timezone**. Without time zone you might get wrong result.

```
var dateFormat = 'ddd D MMM, YYYY - hh:mm A';

moment(moment("Fri 5 Jan, 2018 - 05:00 PM",'Asia/kolkata').format(dateFormat),dateFormat).isValid();
```